# Javascript Color Visualizer - Having Issues with Multiple Paths and selections

Tags: javascript, css, svg, colors, overlay

I'm messing about with this for a friend and I'm having some issues. I use

https://codepen.io/dinos6/pen/XWbBMOw

This is what I have so far:

```js
var svgname = ('Trim-shape');

var sec = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
for (var i = 0; i < sec.length; i++) {
  sec[i].onclick = changeSection;
}

function changeSection(e) {
  // get the section name
  let secname = e.target.getAttribute("data-text");
 // document.write (secname);
  svgname = secname;
 
  // document.write (svgname);
}

// Reference the color shape that was drawn over the image

 var overlay = document.getElementById(svgname);

// Click on a color

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  // get the hex color
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  // set the hex color
  overlay.style.fill = hex;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#Siding-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Siding-shape {
  fill: #0009a2;
}

#Trim-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Trim-shape {
  fill: #fff8a2;
}

#Door-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Door-shape {
  fill: #b90500;
}

#background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.building {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.section {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
<svg id="Siding-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
  
<path id="Siding-shape" d="M733 290l-274 42 1 217 179 4-1-115 90-3 2 122h17l-5-269-9 2z M780 272l-428-84-232 180v10l140-19v-45s43-28 78-36 43-10 80-8 42 8 42 8l1 48 275-43 1-5z M259 363l-135 20v160l138 2V365l-3-2z M1098 388L747 288l3 269 352-47-4-122z" />


<svg id="Trim-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
<path id="Trim-shape" d="M777 225l-4 17-463-82L59 368v-9l251-211 467 77z" />

  

<svg id="Door-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
<path id="Door-shape" d="M278 320v290l181 16-4-343s-55-10-86 0-43 9-91 37z" />
</svg>
  
<img id="background-image" src="https://images2.imgbox.com/ca/36/PUSVCKm8_o.png" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #e1e851" data-hex="#e1e851"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #8cd147" data-hex="#8cd147"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #4a9ccf" data-hex="#4a9ccf"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #661f45" data-hex="#661f45"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #1e2024" data-hex="#1e2024"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="building">
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #333333" data-text="Siding-shape">Siding</div>
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #444444" data-text="Trim-shape">Trim</div>
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #555555" data-text="Door-shape">Door</div>
</div>
```

I used this tutorial to get started:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/09/03/how-to-dynamically-change-the-colors-of-product-images-using-css-blend-mode-and-svg/

I want the buttons on the left to select the different paths of the SVG and allow them to be colored independently, but also for the color selected for each path to highlight and save across different path selections (i.e. if I select door, then red, and then go to trim and back to door, the red swatch should still be highlighted).

I will be the first to say the code is incomplete and buggy, but I'm not that good with javascript and it's been annoying me for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little change

You determine `overlay` only once in your code at starttime. So it isn't changed, if you click on the left buttons.

I transform it to a function which returns the value and then use the function

```js
var svgname = ('Trim-shape');

var sec = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
for (var i = 0; i < sec.length; i++) {
  sec[i].onclick = changeSection;
}

function changeSection(e) {
  // get the section name
  let secname = e.target.getAttribute("data-text");
 // document.write (secname);
  svgname = secname;
 
  // document.write (svgname);
}

// Reference the color shape that was drawn over the image

 function overlay() { return document.getElementById(svgname) };

// Click on a color

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  // get the hex color
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  // set the hex color
  overlay().style.fill = hex;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#Siding-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Siding-shape {
  fill: #0009a2;
}

#Trim-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Trim-shape {
  fill: #fff8a2;
}

#Door-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#Door-shape {
  fill: #b90500;
}

#background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.building {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.section {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
<svg id="Siding-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
  
<path id="Siding-shape" d="M733 290l-274 42 1 217 179 4-1-115 90-3 2 122h17l-5-269-9 2z M780 272l-428-84-232 180v10l140-19v-45s43-28 78-36 43-10 80-8 42 8 42 8l1 48 275-43 1-5z M259 363l-135 20v160l138 2V365l-3-2z M1098 388L747 288l3 269 352-47-4-122z" />


<svg id="Trim-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
<path id="Trim-shape" d="M777 225l-4 17-463-82L59 368v-9l251-211 467 77z" />

  

<svg id="Door-svg" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1169 673">
<path id="Door-shape" d="M278 320v290l181 16-4-343s-55-10-86 0-43 9-91 37z" />
</svg>
  
<img id="background-image" src="https://images2.imgbox.com/ca/36/PUSVCKm8_o.png" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="colors">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #e1e851" data-hex="#e1e851"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #8cd147" data-hex="#8cd147"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #4a9ccf" data-hex="#4a9ccf"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #661f45" data-hex="#661f45"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #1e2024" data-hex="#1e2024"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="building">
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #333333" data-text="Siding-shape">Siding</div>
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #444444" data-text="Trim-shape">Trim</div>
  <div class="section" style="background-color: #555555" data-text="Door-shape">Door</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now to just get the swatches to highlight.

Comment: @RailzGhunn Here is an intermediate solution:https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/RwPBMRq You should go on from there. I'm not going to explain it to you though